# how do you read data in csv file and print specific ones?

Tags: python, csv, input

in my program i ask the user for a number and then proceed to read a csv file using DictReader. I want to output the values in the csv file that are larger then the users number....

```
import csv

limit_amount = raw_input("Please Enter a Limit Amount: ")

with open("transactionsample.csv","rb") as my_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(my_file)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Comment: so whats the problem ?

Comment: im trying to get the program to print a value from the file "transactionsample.csv" only if the value if greater then the limit_amount inputted by the user... right now it prints all values I think i need to assign the row[0] to be the key then use data from a specific row and compare it to the user input

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

limit_amount = int(raw_input("Please Enter a Limit Amount: ")) #convert limit_amount from string to int

with open("transactionsample.csv") as my_file: #rb is really unnecessary
    reader = csv.DictReader(my_file)
    for row in reader:
        for k in row: #check each cell
            if row[k].isdigit() and int(row[k]) > limit_amount: #validation and comparison 
                print row[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to test the value from you `row` you are reading against the user input `limit_amount`. For that you need to know which 'column' you're comparing the user input against, let's say the value you're looking for is at index `2`:

```
import csv

limit_amount = raw_input("Please Enter a Limit Amount: ")

with open("transactionsample.csv","rb") as my_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(my_file)
    for row in reader:
        if row[2] >= limit_amount: # you might have to change the if condition to match exactly what you want
            print row
```